# For a model like this what performance measures can I calculate and how?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, model-evaluation

## Methods:

From the [machine learning literature](http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2010/09/tools-for-machine-learning-performance.html), I understand different parameters can show performance of model in machine learning. I would briefly expand my understanding with confusion matrix:

[image]

(1) **Accuracy**: measures the proportion of correct predictions considering the positive and negative inputs.

(2) **Specificity**: measures the proportion of the true negatives, that is, the ability of the system on predicting the correct values for the cases that are the opposite to the desired one.

**ROC curve:** Considering many thresholds, it is possible to calculate a set of pairs (sensitivity, 1-specificity) which can be plotted in a curve.  This curve will be the ROC curve for the system where the y-axis (ordenades) represents the sensitivity and the x-axis (abscissas) represents the complement of specificity (1 - specificity).

**area under the ROC Curve (AUC)** - higher the ROC curve's area, better the system.

(3) **Sensitivity**: measures the proportion of the true positives, that is, the ability of the system on predicting the correct values in the cases presented.

(4) **Efficiency**: mean of Sensibility and Specificity

(5) **Positive Predictive Value**: the estimation of how good the system is when making a positive affirmation - POSITIVE HITS / TOTAL POSITIVE PREDICTIONS

(6) **Negative Predictive Value**: measure indicates the estimation of how good the system is when making a negative affirmation - NEGATIVE HITS / TOTAL NEGATIVE PREDICTIONS

(7) **Phi (φ) Coefficient**

## My data

I have quantitative y variable with many x quantitative variables and fit a lear regression equation. Objective here is how closely `x` values predict `y` - means that deviation from expectation in both negative and positive direction is not good.

```
#random population of 200 subjects with 1000 variables 

M <- matrix(rep(0,200*100),200,1000)
for (i in 1:200) {
set.seed(i)
  M[i,] <- ifelse(runif(1000)<0.5,-1,1)
}
rownames(M) <- 1:200

#random yvars 
set.seed(1234)
u <- rnorm(1000)
g <- as.vector(crossprod(t(M),u))
h2 <- 0.5 
set.seed(234)
y <- g + rnorm(200,mean=0,sd=sqrt((1-h2)/h2*var(g)))

myd <- data.frame(y=y, M)
```

Let's say I want to fit `ridge` and `lasso` to this:

```
 require(glmnet)

   # LASSO 
   fit1=glmnet(M,y, family="gaussian", alpha=1)

   # Ridge   
   fit1=glmnet(M,y, family="gaussian", alpha=0)
```

## Question:

***What performance measure listed above (or not listed) are relevant here and how can I calculate them?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being that you're facing a regression task, the metrics above are not appropriate: They're for assessing classifier performance. The scikit learn [metrics documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values) provides a handy, quick reference that nests metrics under their appropriate problem types.

In regression, [mean squared error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) (MSE) is the classic measure. You may calculate this by taking the difference of each prediction and actual value, squaring them, and taking the mean of all values. Another measure is the [mean absolute error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error) (MAE), which is less prone to outliers. It is calculated by taking the absolute value of the errors, rather than squaring them. Lower is better in both cases, and here's a basic example:

```
# Suppose that:
#  yTest is your hold-out set for cross-validation
#  Your model was trained using xTrain and yTrain
#  fit1.predictions holds the predictions from using your fitted model on xTest
fit1.meanSquaredError = mean((yTest - fit1.predictions) ^ 2)
fit1.meanAbsoluteError = mean(abs(yTest - fit1.predictions))
```

Many ML packages calculate this for you, and let you select which to use for cross-validation. From the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf), for glmnet uses MSE for cross-validation by default, with the option of MAE. (See `type.measure` on p. 4.)